# What's the difference between instantiating an object and calling getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android

I have inherited an Android app that is calling an activity from the Android.Manifest file

```
STXmaApplication stx_app;

public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView( R.layout.main);
stx_app=(STXmaAplication).getApplicationContext();
stx_app.getModel().addObserver(this);
```

I have looked to see if the object has already been instantiated and can't find it. So I'm wondering if this call forces an instantiation of the object. Note that the next call is a call to one of the app's methods.

Comment: You seem to have a typo there: it should be `stx_app=(STXmaAplication)getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating an object is creating an object instance, what you do with `new`.
It is an OOP concept not exclusive of Android nor java.

On another hand `getApplicationContext()` is Android specific and called in an `Activity` will return the singleton that has been set as the Application instance. There is only one Application instance running for an app, and it is common between the differerent activities of the app, so it is a common place to put some attributes that need to be accessed from different activites, though it has its caveats as an application can be destroyed with no previous notice.

In case of using a custom Application object, it has to be declared in the `application` tag in the Manifest

Answer (score 0):

> So I'm wondering if this call forces an instantiation of the object

No. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you will find an an `<application>` element, with an `android:name` attribute that points to this `STXmaAplication` class. That is causing the object to be instantiated, instead of `android.app.Application`, whenever your process is started. By the time you are making your call, the object already exists.

Answer (score -1):

Both returns same ApplicationContext. So no difference.

**Best practice is to use use singleton method to get `ApplicationContext` anywhere you need in project.**

Call `ApplicationContext.getInstance()` in `Activity, Fragment, Dialog, BroadcastReceiver,` or any where.

your app context class looks like.

```
import android.app.Application;


public class AppContext extends Application {

    private static AppContext mInstance;
    public static final String TAG = AppContext.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        mInstance = null;
    }

    public static synchronized AppContext getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

}
```